# Loop in my htacces in ssl mode

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl

My problem is : when I click in url redirection in 2end levels /, I have this note in browser.

> Firefox a détecté que le serveur redirige la demande pour cette adresse d'une manière qui n'aboutira pas.
>   La cause de ce problème peut être la désactivation ou le refus des cookies."

Note:
 My site works fine without SSL.

Here is my .htacces:

```
SetEnv PHP_VER 5
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php
```

What can I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: Is there a `https://yourdomain/index.php`? If not, that would explain the loop. Try disabling redirection and check.

Comment: hi dears,I think I should disable SSL if I can't get the solution this week.. it's been a month on this issue, I'm sock in roles redirection.thanks for cooperation.

Comment: Problem solved,
By recreating the cache folder, the .htaccess file in that folder was corrupted.
thanks for all